# Pass anonymous function to multiple functions

Tags: php

I have a function, which I'd like to pass as an argument to multiple functions. Is there a way to do this with anonymous functions, in one 'line'.

This is what it looks like without an anonymous function:

```
function my_function( $input ) {
    return $input;
}

add_filter( 'filter_one', 'my_function' );
add_filter( 'filter_two', 'my_function' );
```

Here's what calling `add_filter` once with the anonymous setup would look like:

```
add_filter( 'filter_one', function ( $input ) {
        return $input;
});
```

Does the syntax exist in PHP to do the same for `filter_two` without re-writing the function that's the argument?

Comment: What's wrong with actually defining the function?  If you don't want to have it globally available, define it inside another function to limit the scope.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, I'm just interested to know if there is a way to do it

Comment: @AleksG - you don't get any Hipster Beard points going around doing something as old-skool as actually defining function names...

Comment: @AleksG You can't limit the scope of a function in PHP; you may be thinking of JavaScript, where functions have the same scoping rules as variables. In PHP, a function is global, scoped to a namespace, or is a method or static method of some class. An anonymous function, however, *is* scoped, in that it's a value that can be passed around.

Comment: @CD001 You also don't get the ability to dynamically define ("close over") variables when the function is created; or the ability to know that the function is not callable from any other scope; or the ability to keep code concise by having it in one flow rather than needing to jump out to a separate definition of a two-line function. But sure, if hipster beard points are your thing, feel free to stay proud that your code will run under PHP 4.

Comment: @AleksG In case it's not clear, here's what happens when you define a function inside another function: you get a global function, and an error from running it twice. https://3v4l.org/EC3Zd

Comment: @IMSoP - I wasn't being particularly serious; you *kids* and your fancy new closures can stay off my lawn!... tbh I rarely use *functions* at all - class methods yes, but not functions in the global scope.

Comment: @IMSoP D'oh, of course I'm confusing it with JS.  It's the anonymous function as a variable what I had in mind (along the lines of your answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While often defined inline as a parameter to some function, an anoymous function is just a value which can be used like any other. (To be precise, it is [a `Closure` object](http://php.net/closure).)

So you can assign your callback to a variable, and pass that variable around wherever you like:

```
$noop = function ( $input ) {
        return $input;
};
add_filter( 'filter_one', $noop );
add_filter( 'filter_two', $noop );
```